# Calculate cost based on time increments

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am working with a fee sheet that goes up in `$` increments based on time and I would like Google Sheets to do the math to calculate the cost based on the time entered into a cell.

**Example:** a time value of `1` entered into a cell will always equal `$800`.
Every additional 15 mins adds an additional `$100` to the original `$800`.
i.e.- `1 hour = $800`, `1.25 hrs=$900`, `1.5 hrs=$1000`...

I would like to enter the time in one cell and have the sheet calculate the cost into another cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **BASE + (TIME - BASE) / 15min * EXTRA$**

```
=800+(A4-1)/0.25*100
```

[image: 6]

Comment: Thanks again for answering another one of my questions! You've been most helpful today!Out of curiosity, is there a reason why the calculated value stays at 400 if the "time" cell is empty? I will be working off of a blank sheet for each patient (this is calculating surgical fees based on time), and entering the time as needed, but I noticed that when the time field is blank, the "total" field stays at 400. Not a big deal, I can live with it, just curious.

Comment: its because there is no boundary restriction. you can fix it like: `=IF(A2>=1, 800+(A2-1)/0.25*100, )`

Comment: Yes, I was actually able to fix it myself like:=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),800+(B2-1)/0.25*100)as the cell will either have a number (never less than 1) or not. Looks like it works, when the "time" cell is empty, the "total" cell now says "FALSE"

Comment: @Tera get rid off the `FALSE` with: `=IF(ISNUMBER(B2), 800+(B2-1)/0.25*100, )`